# Does Helix work with Azure Web Apps?

Tags: helix, azure

We're planning to work on a new project that'll use Azure Web Apps, we are also trying to adhere to Helix.
Since by default Azure Web Apps needs VS to do the deployment, is there a solution to deploy Helix based projects?

Answer (score 10):

Helix is just an software architecture pattern, it has nothing to do with how should be deployed. Your statement

> Since by default Azure Web Apps needs VS to do the deployment

is not true. My adivce would be to create separate web deployment packages and deploy  them using msdeploy, from your Release management solution, not directly from Visual Studio.

At the end of [this blogpost](http://blog.baslijten.com/sitecore-on-azure-create-custom-web-deploy-packages-using-the-sitecore-azure-toolkit/) you can find out how to deploy a webdeploy package:

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not familiar with Azure Web Apps, and the tutorials use VS to deploy which lead me to the question.